# Call failed to connect: Connection error (503)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I am trying to use audio call in app, But when I call from a device to other device, It does not connect with device and automatically disconnected with twilio Api. What is that problem occurred in app?

```
2018-11-21 10:43:32.226794+0530 AppName[243:9466] StartCallAction transaction request successful
2018-11-21 10:43:32.279094+0530 AppName[243:7164] providerDidBegin
2018-11-21 10:43:32.279737+0530 AppName[243:7164] provider:performStartCallAction:
WARNING: no real random source present!
2018-11-21 10:43:32.308053+0530 AppName[243:7164] [INFO Twilio] recreateMainTransport, Found valid IPv4 address: IPAddress
2018-11-21 10:43:32.309170+0530 AppName[243:9465] [INFO TVOMakeCallCommand] Call URI: sip:None@chunderm.gll.twilio.com;transport=tls
2018-11-21 10:43:32.722550+0530 AppName[243:7164] provider:didActivateAudioSession:
2018-11-21 10:43:38.396482+0530 AppName[243:9514] TIC TCP Conn Failed [72:0x15ef5ca50]: 1:61 Err(61)
2018-11-21 10:43:38.397055+0530 AppName[243:9514] Task <7129FEF4-4EBE-4AC5-9B34-5E0D002AE56F>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -1004 [1:61])
2018-11-21 10:43:38.399459+0530 AppName[243:9466] Task <7129FEF4-4EBE-4AC5-9B34-5E0D002AE56F>.<1> finished with error - code: -1004
2018-11-21 10:43:38.808257+0530 AppName[243:7164] Call failed to connect: Connection error (503).
```

Comment: Are you using the Twilio Programmable Voice SDK in an iOS app here? What is the code you are using to place the call? And your TwiML App code?

Comment: @phllnash Yes, I am using  Twilio Programmable Voice SDK and Callkit.

Comment: Ok, and what about the code. It's hard to tell what is wrong from a log snippet.

Comment: @philnash I found issue, this is from our server side issue. Notification does not contain body statement, so that issue occurs. Thanks

Comment: Glad you're sorted!